# Python : Defining a variable called in a function imported with "from module import * "

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to define a function in a module that needs a variable to be defined first :

```
def function(string):
    variable.write(string)
```

This function should be called in a script containing :

```
variable = open(filepath, 'w')
...
some script
...
variable.close()
```

Everything works fine if I do the following :

```
import mymodule.myfunctions
mymodule.myfunctions.variable = open(filepath, 'w')
...
some script calling function(string)
...
mymodule.myfunctions.variable.close()
```

But if I want to use "import * " it doesn't work :

```
from mymodule.myfunctions import * 
function.variable = open(filepath, 'w') #does not return an error
function(string) #Returns an error : 'variable' is not defined
```

So I would like to be able to define the variable the way I do it with 'import mymodule.myfunctions' but while using 'import * '... Would you have any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'd recommend *not* defining functions that need a variable to be defined first. Make it an explicit parameter.

Comment: It looks like a pretty bad design.

Comment: I agree with @e4c5. We could probably fix your code to do what you want, but you shouldn't want what you want.

Comment: I definitely agree that this looks bad (it just purely out of lazyness, to avoid writing the same argument again and again), it was meant to be temporary, but I'd like to make it work for the sake of learning something new !

Comment: *"But if I want to use 'import *' it doesn't work"*: Don't use `import *` then.